# Create subdomain using route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, subdomain, amazon-route53

I`m new at all of this...And hope I will get some help on this.

I bought domain and I publish my website (lets call it  example.com) , I`m using ec2 , route 53 and nginx .And now I want to create subdomain (admin.example.com)  and this is where I get stuck.

I try to create new hosted zone (admin.example.com ) and then copy that DNS inside my main hosted zone where I create record set for admin.example.com but it doesnt help. Nothing happens , is there any good tutorial or if anyone can give a clue to me how to make this work.

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: you that subdomain to link with main domain?

Comment: do you use route 53 dns server for main domain?

Comment: Yes.And though nginx ( /etc/nginx/sites-available/default ) to be able to connect it with " location /admin/ { root /home/ubuntu/admin; try file $uri $uri index.html} " @Arman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

In addition the certbot command being run on the server was  `sudo certbot --nginx -d admin.mywebsite.com -d www.admin.mywebsite.com`, as no `www.admin.mywebsite.com` domain needed to exist this argument was removed which resolved for the OP.

**Original**

If you have an existing Route 53 public hosted zone, you do not need to create another public hosted zone for the subdomain.

You can simply create the subdomain in the existing public hosted zone, and then for its value specify the EC2s IP address that is hosting it.

Alternatively if you want to use a different public hosted zone for the subdomain, you can create a new record in your existing hosted zone with a type of `NS`. Then set its values equal to the nameservers of the subdomains public hosted zone.

More information is available in the [Creating a subdomain that uses Amazon Route 53 as the DNS service without migrating the parent domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html) page.

Comment: Thank you for replay. Well I just create it. And I put it with type A - IPv4 ardress but when I go to my subdomain its say "We were unable to find the IP address of the host server"

Comment: Are you sure your DNS is in Route 53? What happens if you perform a DIG on your subdomain in https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/?

Comment: Once more Chris thank you for quick replay.Well now when I go to subdomain page its say connection is not private since I put SSH (lets encrypt ) to my main domain ... I will try to do the same think on my subdomain...And I will reach out to you soon.

Comment: OK great let me know :)

Comment: Well when I try to "attach" SSL on my subdomain I get this error https://ibb.co/zf8stb1   What do you think maybe I should create new hosted zone and then copy that DNS on my main hosted zone and create one more Record that will have type A - IPv4

Comment: This is because certbot is doing a DNS lookup and cannot resolve the record in question, you would need to perform a DIG to validate that the exact record it specifies exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220211/discussion-between-ivan-ivanovic-and-chris-williams).

Comment: Chirs thank you for your help !!! Everything work perfect now !!!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)